# JQuery .post() trouble

Tags: jquery, post, load

I have a jQuery `$.post()` function problem (I think) because of `load()` function.

Normally, I have an `index.php` and it has 3 div areas that are one for header, one for subheader and the last one for page content.

I'm loading some pages with jQuery `load()` function in `index.php`. While I'm loading one page, the page that is being loaded is also posting (with `$.post()`) some information to the another page that has some functions.

(I'm posting the information to `news_function.php` from `news.php`)

```
-news(folder)
    -news_function.php
-index.php
-news.php
```

The problem is that I cannot post the information to `news_function.php`. When I looked the Console of Chrome, I saw the `news_function.php` code in "page content area".

Also I tried action method in form, but it didn't work! Is the `load()` function is dangerous? or maybe the `$.post()` function cannot send the valuable to another page due to all codes is behaving in `index.php`?

Comment: Is the question really that the `$.post` function is in the code that is being loaded with the ajax `load()` method, and is not executed when loaded with `load()`, only if you access the page normally.

Comment: So, Do I have to change structure of codes? If `post()` function is not executed with `load()` function, how can I send something to another page?